# formatting SQL help needed

Tags: sql

I sql in txt file i have to format the  enterie sql.I have to run each query in snowflakeit's 2800 lines.Is there any easy way to format sql?

I appreciate your help

Thanks in advance

Comment: to run a sql command, formatting is not a requirement - that's only for human readability

Comment: use a text editor that provides SQL formatting

Comment: A quick Google search finds tools which will format your code for you.

Comment: formatting the SQL easy to read

Answer (score 0):

I've used this site before to format SQL and works pretty well

[Instant SQL Formatter](https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)